# Is there any limit for cost data upload feature in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I use cost data upload feature in my google analytics using google analytics api. Today I received "(400) Error creating this entity. You have reached the maximum allowed entities of this type", when I tried to upload nested data. I searched google documentation and looked for some limits or quotas, but i didn't find anything. Obviously there is some limit, but where is it described? Do you have any practice how to fix that problem? There should be no problem with daily usage, we upload data only once a day...

Thank you for your answers, Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I don't know, how it is possible, but maybe someone repired some bug. Now we are able to upload cost data to google analytics with the same method as earlier...

Answer (score 0):

Cost data upload limits:

> "New custom data sources can be added at any time, but there is a
> limit of 25 per property" [....]
>
> "Cost data is uploaded as a CSV file to a custom data source for
> a single date. Additional data can be
> appended for a given date, up to a maximum of 20 appends per date"

from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/cost-data-import

So maybe you tried to upload more than 20 datasets for a given date ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem. We've got just 2 sources for that account and it is just first data upload for that data source. Moreover i can add, that data cannot be uploaded on all sources in this account. I tried to create new source (for testing) and there cannot be data uploaded too... Seems like there is some limit for daily uploads count on whole account (all sources together)